# Locking file and reading/writing it

Tags: java, file, locking

I need to lock the file for other programs so that my program only can read and write to this file, other programs cannot.

I writed this code (file is not empty, it has some text)

```java
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\test.txt");
file.createNewFile();

try {
  FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
  FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();
  System.out.println(lock);

  // reading this file
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    System.out.println(reader.read());
    System.out.println("success");
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("read fail");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} catch (Throwable e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But im getting read fail with this error

```
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

But this file is only used by my process

Comment: File locks only work if all other processes check for the same lock.  It must be cooperative.

Answer (score 1):

To lock a file, use a [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

The exact semantics depend on the underlying file system.

You should be able to get a lock via `tryLock` on the channel. If it's not working, in what way is it not working?  Failure to get an exclusive lock is, per the documentation, likely due to it already being open.

Comment: Read the _"Platform dependencies"_ section of the page you linked.  This is unlikely to work unless the underlying OS provides the correct API.  In most OSes locking is ***advisory*** only.  Locks are respected only if both parties are using the same locking mechanism.

Comment: Of course.  You can't do file locking at all if file locking is not supported.  I assumed that went without saying.